# Site deployment failed on netlify

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios, netlify

Here is the [code](https://github.com/mmsoni22/React-Advice-App).

When I run code in my localhost it works correctly, but it shows deployed failed in netlify. The failed deployment message is above link's Readme file.

The index.html in public folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
   
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js in src:

```
import Axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios"
import "./App.css"


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    advice : ""
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchAdvice();
  }
  fetchAdvice = () => {
    axios.get('https://api.adviceslip.com/advice')
      .then((response) => {
          const { advice } = response.data.slip
          
          this.setState({
            advice : advice
          })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div className = "App">
        <div className = "card">
        <h1 className = "header">{this.state.advice}</h1>
        <button className = "button" onClick = {this.fetchAdvice}>
          <span>Give me an Advice!</span>
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js in src: The index.js in the source folder

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App"
import './App.css'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "advice",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1"
   },
 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the build command to `CI= npm run build`.

Comment: @yudhinesh Where can I write this command!

Comment: In the build command.